# spartacus deployement with ccv2 and backend.occ.baseUrl value

Tags: spartacus-storefront, sap-commerce-cloud

From what I've understood from the documentation, I need to set

```html
<meta name="occ-backend-base-url" content="OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE">
```

in index.html

I've done just that, but when I deploy with ccv2, the build runs fine, but the front sends a 502 (bad gateway).
The error is :

> ct() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 10.244.2.13, server: ~^.*spartacus-app.*$, request: "GET /app-fr/fr/EUR/ HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:4200/app-fr/fr/EUR/", host: "something.model-t.cc.commerce.ondemand.com"

From https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/configuring-base-url/ it seems that the value should be replaced by `backend.occ.baseUrl` but I have no idea where that value is set in ccv2.

Note: If I hadcode the value in index.html it works just fine.

Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying on CCv2, make sure you do not set the

```
backend: {
      occ: {
        baseUrl: 'https://localhost:9002', ---> you can comment it out by applying //
      }
    },
```

The Spartacus logic is if the base url is set, then it will use that other than what is set by the meta tag containing the contents for `OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE`

Moreover, `OCC_BACKEND_BASE_URL_VALUE` is substituted under the hood 'automatically' by CCv2, which replaces it with the api of the environment you are deploying to, therefore, you do not need to set a static occ baseUrl in Spartacus.

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem.

It had nothing to do with the configuration of the URL.
**It was a plugin (@ngx-env) or a misconfiguration of it** that was messing with the server (the build was fine).

It was a bit hard to diagnose without any error.

Thanks for your time.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).